# Mass Email user functionality in Sandbox throwing error

Tags: massemailmessage

When I click on Mass Email Users.. I have this message

> Your organization's email privileges have been revoked due to
>   non-compliance with our Terms of Use. Please contact your
>   salesforce.com administrator or submit a case to have a salesforce.com
>   representative contact you.
>
> Click here to return to the previous page.

Can anyone help on this issue...

Comment: Have you contacted SFDC yet?

Comment: Logon to your production org and click Help and Training in the upper right. From there you can open a case/contact support.

Comment: Could it possibly be because you've consistently been busting the 1K/day mass email limit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a new feature in Spring 13 where the access to send email (Administration Setup - Email Administration - Deliverability) is set to "System email only" for newly refreshed sandboxes.

Comment: Note to self: read release notes fully including the section not directly applicable to you

Comment: But, I received a " NO_MASS_MAIL_PERMISSION, Single email is not enabled for your organization or profile.  Single email must be enabled for you to use this feature" exception. If the asker's message talks about non-compliance, how come this is the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible reasons

1)Your mass email option is restricted by salesforce as the error denotes

I had encountered before as salesforce had disabled this option of Mass Email as for non compliance

2)Other would be your user does not have Mass Email Permission in Profile .

Second option is less likely and first option can be cause

Comment: Thanks Mohith for ur swift response..But I have two sandboxes.. Its working fine with one and have this error on the second.. Isn't it strange ?

Comment: Maybe the mass email functionality in one of the sandboxes was abused?

Comment: Hello Mike, What exactly do u mean by abused.. Do u mean refreshing sandbox is not well done ?

Comment: No, just that perhaps a user violated the Terms of Use (perhaps by mistake?) in one sandbox so the other was left alone.